# Get just a float on string using regex

Tags: regex, imacros

how can I get just the float value (73.500) of this string using Regex?

"Aproximadamente 73.500 resultados (0,48 segundos)"

Thank you!

Comment: `\d+\.\d+` ...........

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you're using to handle the regex, but this will probably work in just about any flavor:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Which of course says "find one or more digits, a literal decimal point, and then another one or more digits."

Many flavors of regex will allow the shortcut `\d` to represent `[0-9]`, but this is implementation-specific.

It gets more complicated if you want to be able to handle *any* valid float; in fact, I don't think you can accomplish this with a single regex without logical operators.